# Fix crash due to SIGILL in OpenSSL

Tags: c++, openssl, mips, openwrt

I've read several Q&As here regarding the fact that OpenSSL tries different instructions to test if cpu supports them, which causes SIGILL. But those answers usually state that OP was running the app under gdb, but I'm not. So my app on OpenWrt MIPS router actually crashes when using OpenSSL, whenever I make a call to OpenSSL library. The crash is `illegal instruction`. I actually don't have a backtrace, though my app is a debug build. It works fine on Ubuntu and MacOS.
I made sure that both my executable and ssl libs are of the same cpu architecture.

Result of `cat /proc/cpuinfo`:

```
system type             : Atheros AR9330 rev 1
machine                 : 8devices Carambola2 board
processor               : 0
cpu model               : MIPS 24Kc V7.4
BogoMIPS                : 265.42
wait instruction        : yes
microsecond timers      : yes
tlb_entries             : 16
extra interrupt vector  : yes
hardware watchpoint     : yes, count: 4, address/irw mask: [0x0ffc, 0x0ffc, 0x0ffb, 0x0ffb]
isa                     : mips1 mips2 mips32r1 mips32r2
ASEs implemented        : mips16
shadow register sets    : 1
kscratch registers      : 0
package                 : 0
core                    : 0
VCED exceptions         : not available
VCEI exceptions         : not available
```

What worries me is that toolchain `toolchain-mips_34kc_gcc-5.2.0_musl-1.1.11` mentions 34kc in its name. I wonder if it's ok to build with this toolchain for 24 Kc cpu. Though everything else except for openssl works fine.

So could you please answer what are my options to fix it?

Comment: I don't know a lot about MIPS, but I would suggest that it is highly likely that different CPU models (24Kc and 34Kc) support different instructions (especially, the 34Kc might support instructions that 24Kc doesn't).

Comment: Speaking from experience, Debian/Ubuntu cross-compilers are so broken at times I avoid them at all costs. Does Cavium have a cross-compiler you can use? There should be a `SIGILL` handler installed. I'm guessing either (1) the cross-compiled code is bad and the `SIGILL` is unrelated to OpenSSL (it comes in say, app startup code), (2) OpenWRT is a problem and the signals are not being handled properly, or (3) the OpenSSL configuration and build is bad. Its really hard to say at this point.

Comment: @jww thanks for the opinion. I tracked it down to ssl calls by logs, so no ssl calls - things work fine. I was given this tool chain to compile the app, and as openssl lib in the toolchain does not work smoothly, I think the toolchain is not the official one. So when I replaced openssl libs with official ones (the ones from board vendor), the problem is gone. But I'll keep in mind what you said

Comment: You could try with compiler argument `-march=24k`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the problem was, but the app didn't work with the openssl library provided in the toolchain and copied to target board. When `libopenssl` was installed via `opkg` from official carambola2 repos, the problem is gone. So it must have been some incompatibility.